# Apple Watch: How to recruit users?

Tags: user-research, research, apple, recruitment

There are not a lot of users of the Apple Watch (at least in Germany there are probably less then 1%). Which user group would you recruit for a user test to get reliable results?

I am thinking about:

- iPhone users (newer generation)
- People who plan to buy an Apple Watch
- Other smartwatch users

What do you think would be the best?

Answer (score 2):

Some kind of survey with questions like agree or disagree- "I always want to have the latest technology."

Or even just outright asking (masked amongst other questions so they dont think there's a free watch up for grabs) "Do you plan to get an apple watch?" - ASAP, in the next few months, in the next year, etc...

You should probably be targeting the younger generation I think but from there try and whittle it down into the kind of people who (at least claim) to be likely to get an apple watch before too long.